# Query MongoDB with Nifi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I am sending customer Id to MongoDB with Nifi and want to query MongoDB for this customer.

How do i extract data from another processor, query db and send it to next processor?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the GetMongo processor, you can specify a Query. If you leave it blank, the processor will look in the input FlowFile's for the query, so you must transform your Kafka messages to valid MongoDB queries in JSON format.

Alternatively, you can use the [MongoDBLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mongodb-services-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.mongodb.MongoDBLookupService/) directly. It will translate key-value pairs in the incoming record to valid MongoDB queries automatically.